# How to set a Date to anychart.scales.dateTime().minimum (or maximum)

Tags: javascript, anychart

In [this example](https://playground.anychart.com/api/v8/scales/_samples/anychart.scales.dateTime) they create a dateTime scale and set Date objects to its minimum and maximum.

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    var chart = anychart.line();

    chart.line([
        [new Date('28-Jun-16'), 511],
        [new Date('29-Jun-16'), 507],
        [new Date('30-Jun-16'), 512],
        [new Date('31-Jun-16'), 513],
        [new Date('01-Jul-16'), 515],
        [new Date('02-Jul-16'), 503],
        [new Date('03-Jul-16'), 516]
    ]);

    var dateTimeScale = anychart.scales.dateTime();
    dateTimeScale.minimum(new Date('27-Jun-16'));
    dateTimeScale.maximum(new Date('05-Jul-16'));

    // Set date scale.
    chart.xScale(dateTimeScale);

    chart.title('Set dateTime scale');
    chart.container('container');
    chart.draw();
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.12.0/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

But trying that in my environment, I'm getting this error:

> Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

And that makes sense actually, according to [documentation](https://api.anychart.com/v8/anychart.scales.DateTime#minimum):

> minimum(minimum)
>
> Setter for the scale minimum.
>
> Params:
> Name: minimum
> Type: number <----
> Default: null
> Description: Scale minimum to set.

And also according to the interface in the anychart node module:

```js
    interface DateTime extends anychart.scales.ScatterBase {
    ...
        minimum(): number;
        minimum(minimum?: number): anychart.scales.DateTime;
    ...
```

Both are anychart version 8 -> scales -> dateTime -> minimum

What am I missing?? Thx!

Comment: `But trying that in my environment, I'm getting this error:` Please show us this code, not the code that actually works, so that we can help you to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found the answer yourself. `minimum()` method has a toNumber conversion; it is environment-dependent; it would be easier and safer to just assign a number to it using the `valueOf()` method of the Date object, as shown below.

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    var chart = anychart.line();

    chart.line([
        [new Date('28-Jun-16'), 511],
        [new Date('29-Jun-16'), 507],
        [new Date('30-Jun-16'), 512],
        [new Date('31-Jun-16'), 513],
        [new Date('01-Jul-16'), 515],
        [new Date('02-Jul-16'), 503],
        [new Date('03-Jul-16'), 516]
    ]);

    var dateTimeScale = anychart.scales.dateTime();
    dateTimeScale.minimum((new Date('27-Jun-16')).valueOf());
    dateTimeScale.maximum((new Date('05-Jul-16')).valueOf());

    // Set date scale.
    chart.xScale(dateTimeScale);

    chart.title('Set dateTime scale');
    chart.container('container');
    chart.draw();
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.12.0/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```